# What is the average amount won on a game with probability $p$ of winning $x$ else you win $y$

Tags: probability

If in a game of chance you have a certain probability $p$ to receive $x$ dollars else you receive $y$ dollars. How would you calculate the average money you would make per game? To clarify, for each game you either win $x$ or $y$ so have $p$ chance of $x$ and $(1-p)$ chance of y
Is it as simple as $px +(1-p)y$?
I'm a complete noob when it comes to probability and don't really know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have removed the % symbols in your question because they are a very good way of causing confusion. A probability $p=0.5$ is a 50% chance of something happening, a probability $p=1.0$ is a 100% chance. In this particular question there was not much risk, but as you advance further, it can be **very** confusing if you talk *both* about probabilities between 0.0 and 1.0 and about probabilities between 0% and 100%. It is like mixing centimetres and metres in the same equation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right indeed. It is easy to reach that conclusion if you think of it in a "frequentist" way. Let's say you get a million tries:

On average, you get $x$ $1.000.000 \cdot p$ times

You get $y$ $1.000.000 \cdot (1-p)$ times (still on average)

In total, you get: $$1.000.000 \cdot p \cdot x + 1.000.000 \cdot (1-p) \cdot y$$

Now divide by one million to reach an average of $$p \cdot x + (1-p)\cdot y$$

This logic is easy to understand. Now, you can go to the next step by simply removing the $1.000.000$ factor alltogether. We are talking about averages, so there is no problem of saying something like "out of 1 attempt, we get $x$ exactly $p$ times on average and $y$ exactly $1-p$ times on average". That's what probability means after all

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was having a complete mental blank while trying to figure this out and your explanation made total sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct – the expected payout is $px+(1-p)y$, which follows from the definition of expected value and the set-up of the problem.

That you can simply do this calculation is known as the linearity of expectation.